# Selenium server fails to launch Chromium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-server, webdriver-io

I have a set of acceptance tests written with https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs. I wish to run the tests against real browsers via Selenium Server (WebDriver) and Sauce Labs.  Firefox starts fine, but Chromium (30.0.1599.101 from Debian Wheezy packages) does not.  By just setting `{ desiredCapabilities: { browserName: "chrome" } }` I get `ERROR COULDNT GET A SESSION ID` and Selenium Server console output shows

```
WARN - Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
```

If I start Selenium Server with `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromium` new browser window appears, but the tests never start running and after timeout I get the same `ERROR COULDNT GET A SESSION ID` and Selenium Server console output shows

```
Created new window in existing browser session. 13:43:25.775 WARN - Exception thrown java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[...]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[...]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
[...]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
```

Comment: Apparently I need to have Chrome Driver installed and point `webdriver.chrome.driver` to the driver instead of the browser binary.

Comment: Now, with Chrome Driver, I get a step further.  Chromium starts but tests fail right at the start with `Unknown command 'WaitForAllTabsToStopLoading'` appearing in response.

Answer (score 2):

Please set the ChromeDriver executable path in a right way.

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver")
//Then your Driver instance

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

More Information on ChromeDriver [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home)

Comment: Got a step further after realizing I needed Chrome Driver. Thanks.